# Trying to retrieve all leading Capitalized characters preceded with white-spaces, hyphens, apostrophes, or start of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to retrieve all leading Capitalized characters preceded with white-spaces, hyphens, apostrophes, or start of the string.

**Sample:**

```
var text = "This is a sample about about JJohnny Apple-Seed and old Mc'Donald.";
text.match(/[A-Z]/g)  // returns  -->  ["T", "J", "J", "A", "S", "M", "D"]
```

**Desired output:** `["T", "J", "A", "S", "M", "D"]`

**Updated Final Solution:**

```
var str = "This is a story about JJohnny Apple-Seed and Old Mc'Donald.";
var myRe = /\b([A-Z])/g;

var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null)
{
  var msg = "Found " + myArray[0] + ".  ";
  msg += "Next match starts at " + myRe.lastIndex-1;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard `\b` (word-boundary) metacharacter should get you there:

```
text.match(/\b([A-Z])/g)
```

gives:

```
["T", "J", "A", "S", "M", "D"]
```